# Symfony2 AuthenticationFailureHandler - JSON renderView from RedirectResponse

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony, response

I am using Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle and I'd like to use Ajax for the user login.
I use a service which extend the DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler class:

```
<?php
namespace Marquis\WebsiteBundle\Handler;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;

class AuthenticationFailureHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel, HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options, LoggerInterface $logger = null, Translator $translator = null) {
        parent::__construct($httpKernel, $httpUtils, $options, $logger);

        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            /* @var $formResponse RedirectResponse */
            $formResponse = parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
            $response = new JsonResponse(array('success' => false,
                'message' => $this->translator->trans($exception->getMessage(), array(), 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'form' => $formResponse->getTargetUrl()));
        } else {
            $response = parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

It's working pretty well but I want to get the rendered view into the 'form' JsonResponse value.

Is it possible to generate a view from a RedirectResponse object?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to render a view and show that view on login or register page right?

If so, you can return your view directly, and parse as html from javascript code and append wherever you want.

```
return $this->twig->render("SampleBundle:sample.html.twig", $data); //$data is not required
```

and you can append loaded html to your container like this;

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:"html",
  success: function(response){
    response.append('#container');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this might be a solution but I wanted to use the default Symfony2 Response. I couldn't find a way to get the Reponse object instead of a RedirectResponse but I solved the problem with a $.get with jQuery (using the getTargetUrl() function from the RedirectResponse object).